# What is the location of the default Editor and Display Templates in Asp.net MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Where are the default Razor Editor and Display templates (eg String.cshtml, DateTime.cshtml) located when one installs Asp.Net MVC 3?

Comment: Are you looking for Editor and Display method extensions?? (like for example @Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Name) )

Comment: @MaxZerbini - I plan on using these extensions. I want to fiddle around with the complete default set of these templates.

Comment: These are not templates. These are extension methods of the object HtmlHelper. You can use them or you can develope your extension methods.

Comment: They are not templates as Max Zerbini mentiones. You can however create them yourself by putting partials like String.cshtml in the Shared\EditorTemplates folder under Views.

Comment: @MaxZerbini please put your comment as an answer and I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no default templates.Razor `Editor` and `Display` methods are extension methods of the class HtmlHelper. You can use them or you can develope your own extension methods, like this example.

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            MvcHtmlString result = InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(helper, expression);
            // do modification to result
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have DotPeek or Reflector you can look up the type `DefaultDisplayTemplates` in there you will find the templates.  But be warned they are in Code format, not WebForm or razor format, so a bit more difficult to interpret.

**StringTemplate**

```
internal static string StringTemplate(HtmlHelper html)
{
  return html.Encode(html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue);
}
```

(There was no default DateTime template that I could find)

**DecimalTemplate**

```
internal static string DecimalTemplate(HtmlHelper html)
{
  if (html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue == html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model)
    html.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue = (object) string.Format((IFormatProvider) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:0.00}", new object[1]
    {
      html.ViewContext.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model
    });
  return DefaultDisplayTemplates.StringTemplate(html);
}
```